# Treemap - HierarchicalDataSource - Template

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI's tree map with a hierarchical datasource. I attempted to change the square's colors using the colorField configuration, but it didn't change the color.

So I decided that I would attempt to use a template to not only align some text, but to also set the `background-color` based on a field in the datasource. However, I then ran into an issue where it was indicating in the console that my `Color` field is not defined, so I tried removing just that reference and only reference the `Name` field (which is what I'm setting in the textField configuration), but the same error occurred.

What is odd is that if I remove the template then it renders the text properly, it just doesn't render the correct background color.

This is what I am attempting to use:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    {
      "Name": "CEO",
      "Color": "#e6a800",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "CFO",
          "Level": 3,
          "Color": "#9dddf2",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Name": "Comptroller",
              "Level": 2,
              "Color": "#4db85f",
              "Children": [
                {
                  "Name": "Lead Accountant",
                  "Level": 1,
                  "Color": "#d64d4d",
                  "Children": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Accountant",
                      "Level": 0,
                      "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                    },
                    {
                      "Name": "Clerk",
                      "Level": 0,
                      "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "Senior Auditor",
              "Level": 1,
              "color": "#4db85f",
              "Children": [
                {
                  "Name": "Auditor",
                  "Level": 0,
                  "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "COO",
          "Level": 3,
          "Color": "#9dddf2",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Name": "VP Of Operations",
              "Level": 2,
              "Color": "#4db85f",
              "Children": [
                {
                  "Name": "Field Manager",
                  "Level": 1,
                  "Color": "#4d69d6",
                  "Children": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Field Adjuster",
                      "Level": 0,
                      "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Name": "Home Office Manager",
                  "Level": 1,
                  "Color": "#4d69d6",
                  "Children": [
                    {
                      "Name": "Desk Adjuster",
                      "Level": 0,
                      "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  $("#treeMap").kendoTreeMap({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
      data: data,
      schema: {
        model: {
          children: "Children",
          hasChildren: "Children"
        }
      }
    }),
    colorField: "Color",
    valueField: "Level",
    textField: "Name",
    type: 'Vertical',
    //template: kendo.template($('#organizationalHierarchyTemplate').html())
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="example">
    <div id="treeMap"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script id="organizationalHierarchyTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div style="height: auto; background-color: #= Color #;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">#: Name #</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uzOpInEQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your levels are used to determine the area of each square and they need to add up as you go up the hierarchy. e.g.

```
    var data = [
      {
        "Name": "CEO",
        "Color": "#e6a800",
        "Level": 17,
        "Children": [
          {
            "Name": "CFO",
            "Color": "#9dddf2",
            "Level": 11,
            "Children": [
              {
                "Name": "Comptroller",
                "Color": "#4db85f",
                "Level": 3,
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Lead Accountant",
                    "Color": "#d64d4d",
                    "Level": 3,
                    "Children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Accountant",
                        "Level": 2,
                        "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Clerk",
                        "Level": 1,
                        "Color": "#cdefdc"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": "Senior Auditor",
                "color": "#4db85f",
                "Level": 8,
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Auditor",
                    "Level": 8,
                    "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "COO",
            "Color": "#9dddf2",
            "Level": 6,
            "Children": [
              {
                "Name": "VP Of Operations",
                "Color": "#4db85f",
                "Level": 6,
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Field Manager",
                    "Color": "#4d69d6",
                    "Level": 2,
                    "Children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Field Adjuster",
                        "Level": 2,
                        "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Home Office Manager",
                    "Color": "#4d69d6",
                    "Level": 4,
                    "Children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Desk Adjuster",
                        "Level": 4,
                        "Color": "#c8ccdb"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

In the template, you get the fields from the dataItem object

```
  <script id="organizationalHierarchyTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div style="height: auto; background-color: #= dataItem.Color #;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">#: dataItem.Name #</p>
    </div>
  </script>
```